# Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument type 'Binding<String>'

Tags: swift, core-data, swiftui

I'm trying to edit an item in a separate detail view. I want to have the item details populated inside a textfield after selecting the item from the list.

```
      List {
                    ForEach(vm.savedEntites) { entity in
                        Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")

                        HStack {
                        Button(action: {vm.deleteMemory(entity: entity)}) {
                                       Label("Delete",systemImage: "trash")
       
                                     }
                     
                            Button(action: {
                                    vm.selectedEntity = entity
                                    showingDetailScreen.toggle()}) {
                            Label("Details", systemImage: "pencil")
                                     }
                            
                        }
                    }// list ends here
                    .sheet(isPresented: $showingDetailScreen) {
                        DetailItemView(isVisible: self.$showingDetailScreen, entity: vm.selectedEntity!, text: vm.selectedEntity!)
                           }// sheet ends here
                }
```

The detail item view sheet. This is where i'm getting this error next to TextField

> Cannot convert value of type 'Binding<String?>' to expected argument
> type 'Binding'

```
 struct DetailItemView: View  {
        
        @Environment(\.presentationMode) var presentationMode
        @Binding var isVisible: Bool
        var entity: MemoryEntity
        @ObservedObject var text: MemoryEntity
 
        var body: some View {
           Text(entity.name ?? "No Name")
           TextField(text.name ?? "No Name", text: $text.name)
         ....}
```

This is the CoreData model class for items

```
class CoreDataViewModel: ObservableObject {
    let container: NSPersistentContainer
    @Published var savedEntites: [MemoryEntity] = []
    @Published var selectedEntity: MemoryEntity?
    init() {
        container = NSPersistentContainer(name: "MemoryContainer")
        container.loadPersistentStores { (description, error) in
            if let error = error {
              print("Error loading CoreData. \(error)")
        }
        }
        FetchMemories()
    }
```

Comment: seems like $text.name is optional

Comment: Use this : ```TextField(text.name ?? "No Name", text: Binding(get: {text.name ?? ""}, set: {text.name = $0}))```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Because all core data fields are optional, you have to wrap it into `Binding`. And as you're using core data and may face a lot of optionals, you can create an extension:

```
extension Binding {
     func toUnwrapped<T>(defaultValue: T) -> Binding<T> where Value == Optional<T>  {
        Binding<T>(get: { self.wrappedValue ?? defaultValue }, set: { self.wrappedValue = $0 })
    }
}
```

Use it like this:

```
TextField("title", text: $text.name.toUnwrapped(defaultValue: ""))
```

Comment: Nice workaround however in many cases you need to keep it optional to avoid setting value

Comment: For future reference, Jim Dovey wrote a nice article about this: https://alanquatermain.me/programming/swiftui/2019-11-15-CoreData-and-bindings/